# Upstart process listed as stop/waiting

Tags: scripts, upstart, services

I have this upstart script

When I run: `sudo start poxa` it starts the process but when I run: `initctl list` it shows me that is is `stop/waiting` but when I check `ps aux | grep poxa` it show the process.

And, as expected, when I try to stop it: `sudo stop poxa` it returns: `stop: unknown instance:`

```bash
# Upstart Configuration
# put on /etc/init
description     "Poxa"
author          "Poxa"

start on (filesystem or runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [!2345]

#respawn
#respawn limit 10 5
umask 022

console none

pre-start script
    test -x /home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/bin/poxa || { stop; exit 0; }
end script

pre-stop script
        echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] Stoping..." >> /var/log/poxa.log 2>&1
end script

script
        export HOME=/home/ec2-user
        echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] Starting..." >> /var/log/poxa.log 2>&1
        exec /home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/bin/poxa start >> /var/log/poxa.log 2>&1
end script
```

`ps aux | grep poxa`

```bash
root     29032  0.0  0.1  13656  1720 ?        S    11:42   0:00 /usr/local/lib/erlang/erts-7.0/bin/run_erl -daemon /home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/tmp/erl_pipes/poxa/ /home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/log exec "/home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/bin/poxa" "console"
root     29033  0.3  2.0 318992 21100 pts/1    Ssl+ 11:42   0:00 /usr/local/lib/erlang/erts-7.0/bin/beam -- -root /home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa -progname home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/releases/0.4.3/poxa.sh -- -home /home/ec2-user -- -boot /home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/releases/0.4.3/poxa -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /usr/local/lib/erlang/erts-7.0/../lib -config /home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/running-config/sys.config -pa /home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/lib/consolidated -name poxa@127.0.0.1 -setcookie
poxa -user Elixir.IEx.CLI -extra --no-halt +iex -- console
```

I have made this: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#how-to-establish-fork-count to get the fork count but it returns `44`!

Comment: what does syslog have regarding this process ?

Comment: @PKumar I don't have it installed but with `ps aux | grep poxa` I can see the process running

Comment: then upstart is unable to track running pid check log file while starting and stoping the service

Comment: @PKumar yes, that's exactly the problem and I have no idea why upstart is not tracking it. The log is generated correctly when I run `sudo start poxa` but since it doesn't track the PID I can't stop it, upstart is considering it as a `stopped` job. Maybe forcing a PID?

Comment: @PKumar I have added the output when checking for the `poxa` process, as you can see it has two processes running

Comment: @PKumar I had to add the `expect fork` command to my script ;)

Comment: @PKumar but now it doesn't stop hahah it looks like it is processing something but it doesn't stop

Comment: @PKumar I was wrong, using `expect fork` didn't fix the problem completely, it started the process and I could check that it was running with `initctl list` but I can't stop it, it hangs and `initctl list` shows a different PID number than the one showed with `ps aux`

Comment: @Gerep, Could  you try  `expect daemon` , ref http://askubuntu.com/questions/89518/upstart-script-and-start-stop-daemon

Comment: Didi you tried `start on runlevel [2345]` instead `start on (filesystem or runlevel [2345])`???

Comment: What is the output of the service poxa start? ans about "ps ax | grep poxa" ?

Answer (score 5):

Upstart daemon works with three daemon mode: `no expect`, `expect fork`, `expect daemon`, [6.13.5   Implications of Misspecifying expect](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook)

As you can see at there, you need to check the process fork count.

If you insert `expect fork`, the `"exec /home/ec2-user/poxa/rel/poxa/bin/poxa start"` process needs to `fork` once and `exit`. Also it needs to `fork` twice and `exit` for `expect daemon`. The upstart will `trace` that last child pid.

To run the daemon correctly with the upstart script, you need to check the `fork` of `poxa` process.

Following is my example for upstart and simple daemon.

upstart script in `/etc/init`

```
# egservice - eg daemon
#
# This is an example
# upstart script.

description    "egservice"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
#LOOK Following line, So egdaemon needs to fork just once.
expect fork
respawn

exec /sbin/egdaemon
```

`egdaemon.c` for `/sbin/egdaemon`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /* LOOK following line, just once fork and main does not wait child and die, 
    so new child will be changed to a init's child and also a daemon. */
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        while (1) {
            printf("Example daemon\n");
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this C source file can be compiled to a executable binary with following command.

```
$ gcc -o egdaemon egdaemon.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if adding `expect fork`( below `umask 022` line ) helps. If the poxa binary goes to background this should help upstart to track the pid.